# When does the DOM get loaded with a UIWebView?

Tags: ios

I'm using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: to first execute the following javascript and then to execute addTestListener();

I get the 'adding listener' alert displayed, but never the 'DOM content loaded' alert.
I've tried executing the script everywhere in the UIWebView's lifecycle (loadView, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, webViewDidStartLoad, webViewDidAppear etc.) but I never see the 'DOM content loaded' alert.
Is the JavaScript correct? If so why is it never appearing?

```
var script = document.createElement('script');  
script.type = 'text/javascript';  
script.text = 
var Test =
{
f: function()
    {
        if (!event.originalTarget.defaultView.frameElement) 
        {
            alert('DOM content loaded');
        }
    }
}

function addTestListener()
{
    alert('adding listener');
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { Test.f(); }, false);
}



document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think before `webViewDidStartLoad`,  `DOMContentLoaded` event has already triggered. In `webViewDidStartLoad`, I did the following thing:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert(document.readyState)"];
```

and the result is *complete*.